# Get image url from Netsuite File Cabinet in PHP

Tags: php, netsuite

Is it possible to grab the url Netsuite uses for an item image using the PHP Toolkit? Using this function:

```
function getProduct($id) {

  $service = new NetSuiteService();
  $service->setSearchPreferences(false, 1000);

  $itemInfo = new SearchMultiSelectField();
  $itemInfo->operator = "anyOf";
  $itemInfo->searchValue = array('internalId' => $id);

  $search = new ItemSearchBasic();
  $search->internalId = $itemInfo;

  $request = new SearchRequest();
  $request->searchRecord = $search;

  $searchResponse = $service->search($request);
  $products = $searchResponse->searchResult->recordList->record;

  return $products;

}
```

I can get the item information. In the information, netsuite gives me this little snippet (the whole thing is truncated for cleanliness):

```
...
[storeDisplayImage] => RecordRef Object
    (
        [internalId] => 19876
        [externalId] => 
        [type] => 
        [name] => 4010024.jpg
    )
...
```

This just tells me the name of the file in the Netsuite file cabinet. How do I download that image automatically using the PHP Toolkit?

Comment: Show us some code to discuss.

Comment: I've updated the question with code.

Comment: Where are you going to use this image, inside or outside NetSuite?

Comment: Outside. I wanted to download the image to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$request2 = new GetRequest();
$request2->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$request2->baseRef->internalId = $product->storeDisplayImage->internalId;
$request2->baseRef->type = "file";
$getResponse2 = $this->service->get($request2);
if (!$getResponse2->readResponse->status->isSuccess) {
        echo "GET ERROR";
} else {
    $file = $getResponse2->readResponse->record;
    echo "GET SUCCESS, File name is " . $file->name;
    echo "<img src='".$file->url."'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to look at:

```
["storeDisplayImage"]=>
 object(RecordRef)#20 (4) {
   ["internalId"]=>
    string(6) "758653"
    ["externalId"]=>
    NULL
    ["type"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    string(26) "image_name.jpg"
  }
```

I cannot find any way to actually access the image, but if it is possible, the internalId (758653) is what you should be using to search. It is used when accessing the image via URL:

https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=**758653**&c=ACCOUNT#&h=31578b297cc0be65db1f&expurl=T

The problem is that random hash at the end of the URL. I can't quite figure out what it is, but if you could, you would be able to construct that URL.

EDIT: nlapiResolveURL might help you. Try passing the internalId to nlapiResolveURL and it could provide that URL dynamically.